# How do I make a Catch-All Route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I need a Laravel `routes.php` entry that will catch all traffic to a specific `example.com/premium-section` of the site so that I can prompt people to become members before accessing the premium content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In app/Http/routes.php I create a route that will catch all traffic within domain.com/premium-section/anywhere/they/try/to/go and attempt to find and execute a matching function within PremiumSectionController
2. But there aren't any matching methods, just a catch-all.

   ```
   Route::group(['as' => 'premium-section::',
                 'prefix' => 'premium-section',
                 'middleware' => ['web']],
                 function(){
                    Route::any('', 'PremiumSectionController@premiumContentIndex');
                    Route::controller('/', 'PremiumSectionController');

                 });
   ```

.

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use ...

    class PremiumSectionController extends Controller{

        public function premiumContentIndex(){
           return 'no extra parameters';
        }

        //magically gets called by laravel
        public function missingMethod($parameters = array()){
            return $parameters;
        }

    }
```

Comment: so that route will catch 'domain.com/premium-section/anywhere/they/try/to/go' ?

Comment: ya, I posted my Q and my A together.

Comment: Having the parameters as an array is handy if you need to build a redirect()->route('somwhere-else', $withParams)

Answer (score 54):

You could also catch 'all' by using a regex on the parameter.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'premium-section'], function () {
    // other routes
    ...
    Route::get('{any}', function ($any) {
        ...
    })->where('any', '.*');
});
```

Also can catch the whole group if no routes are defined with an optional param.

```
Route::get('{any?}', function ($any = null) {
    ...
})->where('any', '.*');
```

This last one would catch `example.com/premium-section` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder why Laravel is not coded to work with a simple `Route:any('*')`!

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Just a tip, It'd be better not to use Closures, because they can't be cached.
```Route::get('/{action}', 'SiteController@defaultPageHandler')->where('action', '.*');``` would be better ;)

Comment: @LeonidDashko `Route::fallback` would be better as it is just a shortcut for exactly that.

Comment: @lagbox I guess they can't be cached as well :)
But it's good to know about this alternative.

Comment: `Route::fallback` is not a closure, so it can be cached

Answer (score 46):

This does the trick:

```
Route::any('/{any}', 'MyController@myMethod')->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: i always get a "too few arguments" error EDIT: you'll also need a `/` route, otherwise hitting the actually root homepage will result in a 500 error

Comment: just add the `?` to the parameter and will catch even the root uri ie: `{any?}`

Answer (score 8):

Laravel now has a built-in method for this:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#fallback-routes

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
// The catch-all will match anything except the previous defined routes.
Route::any('{catchall}', 'CatchAllController@handle')->where('catchall', '.*');
```