# laravel route with scalable segments length

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes, apache2

I want to only allow the priviledged user to download some special file.

So I config apache2 with below, which make `/data/model/userModel` cannot directly accessable.

```
Alias /user_model "/data/model/userModel"
<Directory /data/model/userModel>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
</Directory>
```

While the `/data/model/userModel` may have subfolders, like

- `/data/model/userModel/pic/tiny/aaa.png`
- `/data/model/userModel/txt/aaa.txt`
- `/data/model/userModel/model/0/13/aaa.zip`

This path is just for file download, in the controller method I just check if the user have to right to download file. So I try to use only one route for these pathes. For example,

```
Route::get('user_model/*', 'ModelController@user_model');
```

While it not works. The `*` in the route only can match one segment of the url.

How can I make one route match url with scalable segments length. **I don't know my design of the route here is proper.**

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831175/how-do-i-make-a-catch-all-route-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a Catch-All Route in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831175/how-do-i-make-a-catch-all-route-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: @NathanHeffley thank you. it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enlighted by [How do I make a Catch-All Route in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34831175/6521116) in [Nathan Heffley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8864044/nathan-heffley)'s comment , I solve it.

Use `Route::get('user_model/{path}', 'ModelController@user_model')->where('path', '.*');` instead of `Route::get('user_model/*', 'ModelController@user_model');`.

**Note:**

- `*` in `Route::get('user_model/*', 'ModelController@user_model');` only can match one segment.
- `*` in `Route::get('user_model/{path}', 'ModelController@user_model')->where('path', '.*');` can match multi segments.