# Get the value which comes after the domain name in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

how to create route in laravel for the below 2nd option....

1. http://localhost:8048/
2. http://localhost:8048/content/645668/nice-up-civic-poll.html

**1st** it redirects to home page which is correct for me.

**2nd** I need to get what ever comes after 8048/

so basically **content/645668/nice-up-civic-poll.html** is a parameter which I need to deal with it separately and its dynamic link.

Route api in laravel :

**Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');**

www.example.com will load home page with all stories.

The below links as an example should get the value after www.example.com/ basically its a story/article link so when that comes specific story will be displayed.

www.example.com/content/645668/nice-up-civic-poll.html

www.example.com/content/283206/something-here.html

www.example.com/content/234323/good-nice.html

www.example.com/content/451425/breakup-actor.html

www.example.com/content/365412/accident-occured.html

So basically get everything after domain name which is using apache server.

**.htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Maybe you're looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831175/how-do-i-make-a-catch-all-route-in-laravel-5-2.

Comment: @ceejayoz i have updated the question

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried with the link given by you but still it shows laravel 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a home route and then every other URI to go to a single Controller method you can make a catch-all route:

```
Route::get('{catch}', 'SomeController@action')->where('catch', '.*');
```

This would catch any URI that doesn't match any previously defined route.

If you want everything to go to one place:

```
Route::get('{catch?}', ....)->where(...); // optional param
```

Post about creating a catch all route, answer using regex conditions on parameter:

[SO - How do I make a Catch-All Route in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831175/how-do-i-make-a-catch-all-route-in-laravel-5-2)

**Update:**

If these URIs you need to catch all have the same format,

```
www.example.com/content/645668/nice-up-civic-poll.html
```

you can register a route to match that format instead of catching everything possible:

```
Route::get('content/{id}/{slug}', function ($id, $slug) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: 'not working' ... means you have an expectation of something and yet you are getting a different result ... you have to articulate what those are, as 'not working' doesn't have any context

Comment: @lagobx the code which you gave doesn't work still I get laravel 404 error.
To better understand i have provided with .htaccess file and examples in my original question

Comment: what 404, apache 404 or laravel 404?

Answer (score 1):

try using $request helper..

```
$leftbehind = str_replace($request->getHost(),'', $request->fullUrl());
```

or try this..

```
$request->getRequestUri();
```

Comment: But it doesn't hit any api in laravel so that i can somehow get the value of it... rather it displays 404 not found page

Answer (score 0):

Use `$request->path()`

> The path method returns the request's path information. So, if the incoming request is targeted at `http://example.com/foo/bar`, the path method will return `foo/bar`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#request-path-and-method

Comment: But it doesn't hit any api in laravel so that i can somehow get the value of it... rather it displays 404 not found page

Answer (score 0):

You can use The `Request::path()` to get the current url.

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html - Check this for all the options available for `Request`.

eg: If you want to just check whether the users is in some url or not use this - `Request::is('/url') // This will return true or false`

Answer (score -1):

You can use php's built in function, `parse_url` to retrieve content/645668/nice-up-civic-poll.html.

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)
```

Comment: But it doesn't hit any api in laravel so that i can somehow get the value of it... rather it displays 404 not found page

Comment: @Sharath If that URL doesn't go to Laravel, you've misconfigured your server. Is it Laravel's 404 or the server's?

Comment: I think what the op wants is something like `Route::get('/{slug}', ...);` where slug can contain content/645668/nice-up-civic-poll.html. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ceejayoz it is laravel's 404 error...  its treating /content/124553/ as a path  but its a param for me...

Comment: Why dont you reconsider you url structure and pass your /content/12345... as url param instead?

Comment: @PaulSantos can't do because from the mobile apps it redirects to www.example.com/content/....... in this manner. So mobile apps and other places needs to be updated which is not possible. Earlier it was written in plain php which was working fine... Now we have converted to laravel.

Comment: Can you try this brother, 'Route::get('/{path?}, 'controller@func')->where('path', '.*');'