# VueJs page gives 404 on refresh

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I just uploaded my blog app to a test server. When I click on post from the homepage I am able to view the single page using the slug URL. However, from the single page, If I refresh the page it gives me a 404 page.

I had used something like the below for my users component:

```
Route::get('/admin/users{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('admin');
})->where('vue_capture','[\/\w\.-]*');
```

This is how my routes.js looks like:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Admin from './components/Admin.vue';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage.vue';
import Subscriber from './components/subscriber/Main.vue';
import Single from './components/Single.vue';
import Categories from './components/Categories.vue';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Homepage
    },
    {
        path: '/subscriber',
        component: Subscriber
    },
    {
        path: '/post/:slug',
        name: 'post',    
        component: Single
    },
    {
        path: '/categories/:slug',
        component: Categories
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});
```

And my Laravel routes are like this:

```
<?php
use App\User;
use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;
use App\Http\Resources\UserCollection;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('homepage');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout' );
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

/************************************************************
                            API'S
************************************************************/
Route::get('/api/homeposts', 'HomePostsController@posts')->name('homeposts');
Route::resource('/api/users', 'AdminUsersController');
Route::resource('/api/posts', 'AdminPostsController');
Route::resource('/api/categories', 'AdminCategories');
Route::get('/api/loggedUser', 'AdminUsersController@loggUser')->name('singleUser');
Route::put('/api/updatedUser/{id}', 'AdminUsersController@updateUser')->name('singleUserUpdate');

Route::resource('/api/subscriber', 'SubscriberController');
/*Route::get('/admin/users{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('admin');
})->where('vue_capture','[\/\w\.-]*');*/

/************************************************************
                        ADMIN ROUTES
************************************************************/
Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/admin/users', 'AdminUsersController@users')->name('allusers');
    Route::resource('/admin/posts', 'AdminPostsController');
});

/************************************************************
                    SUBSCRIBER ROUTE
************************************************************/
Route::group(['middleware'=>'subscriber'], function(){
    Route::get('/subscriber/{vue_capture?}', function () {
        return view('homepage');
    })->where('vue_capture','[\/\w\.-]*');
});

/**********************************************************/

Route::get('/single/post/{slug}', 'AdminPostsController@single');
```

But how exactly can I handle for the single post page?

Comment: can you post your laravel entry point route? I mean home route.

Comment: and please make sure that you add it at the BOTTOM of he `routes/web.php` file

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Assuming your entry point is the `index` method of your `HomeController`,
you just need to add this route at the bottom of your `routes/web.php` file.

```
Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('homepage');
})->where('any','.*');
```

Comment: It doesnt give me any error, but I cannot see any vue component

Comment: I already updated it. and also please make sure to put it at the BOTTOM of the web.php file

Comment: Yes yes, I placed that at the bottom of the file and it now works.
Mind explaining the code and perhaps indicate a link where I can read more about it?
Appreciate the support otherwise.

Comment: In order for your router(vue-router) to work, you need to do something with your laravel router, which is to forward it the request to your entry point so that vue-router will be able to handle it instead of laravel.

Comment: Understood that part. And what if my entry point was not the index method of my HomeController?

Comment: What we basically did here is tell laravel that if a route is not defined, just show the home page. and with this, vue will be able to handle it, if laravel can't handle it.

Comment: it doesn't really matter, you just need to tell laravel to display your view where your vue entry point or `app.js` is included if there is no available route in laravel that can handle it.

Comment: Got it. Once again appreciate the support.
Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an issue with Vue.

When I visit the webpage http://blog.sidneylab.com/post/quasi-non-est-magnam-quae-aut-omnis-nisi (the first post on your website), I get a `404` error from the server itself. Same with anything else on `/post/`

That means your route handler isn't sending the relevant Vue index or code when a route matches. Ensure it does this with either the `/post/` URL or just add a [catch-all handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831175/how-do-i-make-a-catch-all-route-in-laravel-5-x) at the bottom of your default route handler:

```
Route::get("{any}", "DefaultHandler@myMethod")->where("any", ".*");
```

Answer (score 0):

add in the bottom of `web.php`

```
Route::get('{path}', 'HomeController@dashboard')->where('path','([A-z\d\-\/_.]+)?')`
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is:

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('layouts.master');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

This helps the Laravel to capture URLs generated by Vue! That's it!